# Use 2 jquery libraries on same web page

Tags: jquery

I'm currently developing a web page using two plugins: Fancybox and SlidePanel. Both of the plugins present on the same page. Fancybox requires 1.9.0 library version and slidepanel requires 1.4.2 library version. When I use two libraries at once, only one of them works (only fancybox works, or only slidepanel works). How to use those 2 libraries at once at same page?

I have tried changing the 1.4.2 to 1.9.0 version ONLY if the fancybox is clicked:

```
$('a.fancybox').click(function(e){
    $('script#jquery_loader').attr('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js');
    $('a.fancybox').fancybox();
```

});

That did not work. I also have tried `google.load("jquery", "1.9.0")` on click but apparently version 1.8 and up did not support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember you should only use **one version of jquery at a time** - So make sure you are not loading 2 instances of jquery, that normally breaks stuff.
Inspect your page in the browser and make sure you only have one library loaded...

Try using only version 1.8.3 - http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js

Comment: thanks a lot, 1.8.3 works for both plugins, amazing i didnt realize that

Comment: cool man...glad I could help. To date, 1.8.3 is the most stable/safe to use (according to my knowledge)

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery Migrate or if that doesn't work you can try this (untested):

Try to use the dollar sign to call the most up to date version and another variable to call the other one.

First load the oldest scrtip and open a script tag:

```
<script>
    oldJquery = jQuery;
</script>
```

Ather this load the most recent version and declare $ = jQuery;

instead of using $('selector') now use oldJquery('selector') for the first librabry

Comment: would have to be `oldJQuery = jQuery`. jQuery is named with a lower case j

Comment: thanks, some of it works, but the problem goes within its own functions not variables anymore

Answer (score 0):

-- use " jQuery Migrate plugin " with jquery 1.9

http://jquery.com/download/

-- as they said

We have created the jQuery Migrate plugin to simplify the transition from older versions of jQuery. The plugin restores deprecated features and behaviors so that older code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9 and later

Comment: thanks, might check it later, 1.8.3 works for both plugins though